# Does android applications run on different processes?

Tags: android

I have a question regarding how android processes run on a device. So for different applications, do they run on different processes? And if I were to start a implicit intent to start another application, would the device switch to another process to run the other application or it runs the other application in the current process? Thanks!

Comment: It will run in it's own process and also each app may have multiple processes

Answer (score 0):

> By default, all components of the same application run in the same
> process and most applications should not change this. However, if you
> find that you need to control which process a certain component
> belongs to, you can do so in the manifest file.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads

If you start another app with an intent, that will run in it own process.